# Chart.js do not display in Boostrap tabpanel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I have some issue to get my Chart.js working correctly with Twitter Bootstrap tabs. It won't load for some reason. I don't know if there's a way of doing this in the settings or a workaround. This is my code:

```html
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">
    <canvas id="vchart" width="1140" height="300"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var vChartData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        datasets: [{
          label: { % trans '"Visitors"' %
          },
          fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          data: [40, 50, 60, 90, 100, 155, 180, 190, 200, 500, 170, 200]
        }, {
          label: { % trans '"Unique Visitors"' %
          },
          fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          data: [20, 25, 30, 45, 50, 70, 100, 80, 60, 80, 70, 100]
        }]
      }
      var vChart = document.getElementById('vchart').getContext('2d');
      new Chart(vChart).Line(vChartData);
    </script>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="month">

  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="year">

  </div>
</div>
```

When I load the page it won't show from the beginning and if I try switching tabs back and forth it will not display either.

Is there a good solution (workaround) for this?

Answer (score 0):

info here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

use something like this

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  // here redraw your chart
})
```

**UPD:** make demo for you http://jsfiddle.net/serGlazkov/291w2jLk/145/

Comment: Thanks! But that still didn't load it when I added the JS into that. I have very limited knowledge about JS so I probably forgot to do something. I added my edit in the question if I did something wrong you could see.